# What is twisted triangular two-torus also called a triangular doughnut?

Tags: spectral-theory

In "A Geometry of Music" by Dmitri Tymoczko Oxford 2010, the authors says that mathematicians refer to a particular lattice in what mathematicians would call "the interior of a twisted triangular two-torus, otherwise known as a triangular doughnut.

What is the correct equation for that?

Comment: See "The Sensual Quadratic Form" by John Horton Conway. I am pretty sure you are asking about isospectral domains, Conway gives some detail but stays elementary.